# Regex to negate certain characterss

Tags: regex

I need some help with regex to extract specific characters from a given string. Following is the string and required string to extract.

```
21.4R3.13-EVO -- Required 21.4R3-EVO 
24.1R13.13-EVO -- Required 24.1R13-EVO 
21.4R2-S1-20190223000107.0-EVO  -- Required 21.4R2-EVO 
19.4R11-S1-20190223000107.0-EVO  -- Required 19.4R11-EVO
```

I tried following and its matching first half but I couldn't negate the middle section.

```
[0-9]+.[0-9]+[A-Z][0-9]+

Matching
21.4R3
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex for search:

```bash
^(\d+\.[a-zA-Z\d]+)[-.].*(-[a-zA-Z]+)$
```

and replace with `$1$2`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VzZg7w/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(\d+\.[a-zA-Z\d]+)`: Match 1+ digits then a dot followed by 1+ alpha numeric character. Capture this in group #1
- `[-.].*`:
- `(-[a-zA-Z]+)`: Match last `-` followed by 1+ letters and capture in group #2
- `$`: End